# React Router 4 - passing state in Link component

Tags: react-router-v4

React newb here, I've noticed when I pass state with the router Link component to another component ie:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/myPath', state: { foo: myVar } }}>Text</Link>
```

when Link is clicked myPath loads, then I can access `myVar` by typing `this.props.location.state.foo`. even if the page is reloaded (browser refresh), `myVar` isn't lost and still holds its value which is what i want

another way i can get to myPath in my app is by `this.props.history.push("/myPath")`. can i achieve the exact same functionality as the Link component doing it this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried but from the [document](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history), `history.push` accepts optional state object as well:

```
push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack
```

I would try `this.props.history.push('/myPath', { foo: myVar });`.